# Hibernate not Injecting Parameters in Query Annotation

Tags: java, hibernate

I've read the documentation on inserting method parameters into queries and other questions however they all suggest that this should work.

```
 @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM period WHERE time LIKE \":day%\" AND id IN (SELECT id FROM booking)", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Booking> findAllBookingsOnDay(@Param("day") String day);
```

Results in:

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM period WHERE time LIKE ":day%" AND id IN (SELECT id FROM booking)
```

I've tried removing quotations and percentage but that just results in.

```
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM period WHERE time LIKE ? AND id IN (SELECT id FROM booking)
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this is to just use an unescaped placeholder in the query, and the bind the `LIKE` wildcard expression to it from the Java side.

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM period WHERE time LIKE :day AND id IN (SELECT id FROM booking)", nativeQuery =true)
List<Booking> findAllBookingsOnDay(@Param("day") String day);
```

Usage:

```java
String day = "%friday%";   // or whatever value would make sense here
findAllBookingsOnDay(day);
```

Comment: Ah I see now but I’m not sure I understand the difference

Comment: The difference is that the correct pattern is to bind a string literal to a bare `?` placeholder.  You were trying to put the like and escape characters hard coded into the query string.

Comment: Oh ok I see now. Thanks so much for the help